# How to Code coverage for List of Single email content in Apex Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Apex method:

```
webservice static boolean sendEmail(id opptyId, id duplicateid) {
    //Approval Email Body content
    PageReference SEmail = Page.Sales_ApprovalPage;
    SEmail.getParameters().put('oppId', opptyId);  

    //Email service custom setting
    Salescomponent__c emailInstance = Salescomponent__c.getInstance('EmailService');

    if(emailInstance == null || emailInstance.Value__c == '') {
        return false;
    }

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    mail.toAddresses = new String[] { duplicateid};
    mail.subject = 'Approval Required for Opportunity ['+opptyId+']';
    mail.setHtmlBody(semail.getcontent().toString());
    mail.setReplyTo(emailInstance.Value__c);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

    allmsg.add(mail);

    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg);

    if (results[0].success) {
        System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
        return true;
    } else {
        System.debug('The email failed to send: '+ results[0].errors[0].message);
        return false;
    }

}
```

I am not able to code cover of below part

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

mail.toAddresses = new String[] { duplicateid};
mail.subject = 'Approval Required for Opportunity ['+opptyId+']';
mail.setHtmlBody(semail.getcontent().toString());
mail.setReplyTo(emailInstance.Value__c);
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

allmsg.add(mail);

Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg);

if (results[0].success) {
    System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
    return true;
} else {
    System.debug('The email failed to send: '+ results[0].errors[0].message);
    return false
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail just what it is you can't cover? I'm guessing it is that you can't actually send email in a test and cannot handle success/fail cases. To handle similar we have a separate object for sending emails and this allows mocking of responses when executed in the context of test execution. That way you can pretend to send emails and (on a test-by-test basis) ask for a failure to be returned or not. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yes, Exactly Vijay. How to To handle similar as you said we have a separate object for sending emails and this allows mocking of responses when executed in the context of test execution? I mean what is that object to handle sending email in a test class and How?

Comment: Can you add your test class code?

Comment: In this particular instance, I'd bet that the reason why you're not getting coverage for anything below the check for your `SalesComponent__c` custom setting is that your test isn't inserting any records for your custom setting (hence `emailInstance` would be null, fail your check, and return early).

Answer (score 2):

My suggested approach is to add a new class that handles sending the emails and returning the results. You can then mock this out in tests.

Let's assume your sending class looks like:

```
public virtual class MyMessaging {
    public virtual Messaging.SendEmailResult[] sendEmail(List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages) {
        return Messaging.sendEmail(message);
    }
}
```

Now you can update your class to be:

```
public class MyClass {
    // NOTE: This is the extra static attribute you need
    @TestVisible
    private static MyMessaging myMessaging = new MyMessaging();

    webservice static boolean sendEmail(id opptyId, id duplicateid) {
        //Approval Email Body content
        PageReference SEmail = Page.Sales_ApprovalPage;
        SEmail.getParameters().put('oppId', opptyId);  

        //Email service custom setting
        Salescomponent__c emailInstance = Salescomponent__c.getInstance('EmailService');

        if(emailInstance == null || emailInstance.Value__c == '') {
            return false;
        }

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        mail.toAddresses = new String[] { duplicateid};
        mail.subject = 'Approval Required for Opportunity ['+opptyId+']';
        mail.setHtmlBody(semail.getcontent().toString());
        mail.setReplyTo(emailInstance.Value__c);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

        allmsg.add(mail);

        // NOTE: This is the line that changes
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = myMessaging.sendEmail(allmsg);

        if (results[0].success) {
            System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
            return true;
        } else {
            System.debug('The email failed to send: '+ results[0].errors[0].message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When unit testing you can then do something like:

```
@IsTest
class MyClassTest {
    class MyMessagingMock extends MyMessaging {
        public Messaging.SendEmailResult[] sendEmail(List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages) {
            // Generate mock results in some way. If you can't create Messaging.SendEmailResult
            // instances directly you can probably do it using JSON.deserialize
            return whatever;
        }

    @IsTest
    void testSendMail() {
        MyClass.myMessaging = new MyMessagingMock();

        ...
    }
}
```